# The Stanley Parable: Confusion ending

Tags: the-stanley-parable

Is getting to the confusion ending schedule the confusion ending itself? The first time I got to the schedule and the narrator "forgot" about the restarts, I followed all the instructions, expecting for something to go wrong as the schedule indicated, but I managed to get through to the "happy" ending. The second time I tried triggering the confusion ending again, but after the "initial" restart I got to the two-door room with both doors closed, just like before, and stopped playing there, assuming I was just going to "loop" the confusion ending.

Am I missing something? Should I keep going/exploring with this ending?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not so sure that's the ending.

The schedule says that after the restart, the player is supposed to find the yellow line again, but be unable to play (paraphrasing here).

After seeing the schedule, I've found the yellow line, but I can't get to it.

> After seeing the schedule, the narrator restarts the game. Head through the "door on the right". On your right There is an office with a window and no marking on the door. Through that window you can see the yellow line starting (or ending?) in that office. If you look into the office anytime before seeing the Confusion Ending Schedule, the yellow line is not there. The door to the office is locked. [image: No Line] [image: Schedule] [image: Line Is Back]

Comment: Thanks Steve! I was looking for a "spoiler" tag, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I just saw this as well. A second restart after seeing the line in that room reverts back to the no-line version of that room (at least for me). I don't know if it's just an "easter egg" type thing, or if there's actually a way to reach the line at that point.

Comment: @aarondev We don't need a spoiler tag in this answer seeing as the question is clearly talking about this ending.

Comment: It is possible to reach the line using the console command `ent_remove` but the line simply stops shortly afterwards.  [Here is a picture of the line for the other side](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vk03P.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is where it ends. If you read the list of events, the narrator is supposed to restart, but he decides not to and, after a bit, the timer stops. The narrator then mentions something about stopping the cycle and talks until the game resets itself, thus breaking symmetry.
At least that's how I saw it.